# GitLab Pipeline Not Running Using Rules Workflow

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, pipeline, cicd

I've included the rule to run on develop branch always, I've also confirmed the CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is develop. Any Ideas? The pipeline doesnt run at all, all stages are skipped. I've read the documentation countless times.

```
# List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
stages:          
  - validate
  - build


workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: always
      
# Variables set in the GitLab UI are not passed down to service containers. 
# To set them, assign them to variables in the UI, then re-assign them in your .gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  CI_COMMIT_BRANCH: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    



validate-job:
  stage: validate
  script:
  - echo "Validated"


build-job:
  stage: build
  ##some job actions
  script: 
  - echo "t"
  # rules:
    # - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /develop\/.*$/
      # when: always
```

UPDATE: Only .pre / validate stages run in GitLab.

Answer (score -1):

Try out what happens when you

1. place an "export" command in a job so that you get the variable values
2. deactivate the workflow rule (comment it out)
   logged in the job output.

The value of the CI_COMMIT_BRANCH variable will not be as expected.

Comment: I didn't need to export it as it's a CI variable so I just took the rules out and echo'd it in the build stage - confirming it's develop.

Comment: I tried myself. The output of  
`- echo "CI_COMMI_BRANCH=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"`   
was  
`CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}`  
but not the expected  
`CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=develop`